# Could someone explain to me what BIDENT is please

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

While checking a newly-created tabled, I found this

```sql
[PhysicalStoreID] dbo.bident not null
```

It was made as a column which copies ID column from another table.
[image: it was made as a column which copies ID column from another table.]

As I understand, `BIDENT` is a data type which connect two columns in different tables.
Could someone explain to me please how this works, what `BIDENT` is, and why isn't there a foreign key used?

Comment: `BIDENT` isn't a build-in data type in SQL Server. I *assume* it's a user defined [scalar] data type. The fact you reference it as `dbo.bident` in the text of your question as well is proof of this, as it's schema qualified.

Comment: Personally, I don't really see much point in the use of user defined scalar (or alias) data types any more, as they are basically just aliases. You can't put any validation on them, as things like `RULE`s have no effect on them and they (`RULE`s) are deprecated.

Comment: As for explaining what `BIDENT` is, honestly we have no idea. How it works? Well, as i mentioned, it's a "Alias" data type; basically it'll be a synonym for something like `varchar(20)` or `decimal(12,2)` (again, we have no idea what). It won't maintain any referential integrity or anything, that's a foreign key constraint's job.

Comment: Why don't you ask the creator of this "newly created table"?

Comment: Btw, that's a rather cool name that your colleage gave to the user-defined type. A "bident" is like a spear with 2 tips. The weapon of Hades, the ruler of the underworld in Greek mythology.

Answer (score 4):

As has been mentioned in the comments, this is not a built-in type, but rather a *user-defined type*.

Ideally, you'd ask the person who created the type, which is probably one of your colleagues. Alternatively, you can check SQL Server's system tables:

```
select * 
from sys.types 
where is_user_defined = 1;
```

Note the `system_type_id` of your user-defined type and find the entry in `sys.types` for which `is_user_defined` is 0, but which has the same `system_type_id`. This is the underlying type for which your user-defined type is an alias.